# GMaps V3 InfoWindow - disable the close "x" button

Tags: jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

From what I see, in v2 of GMaps API there was a property "buttons" of the InfoWindow object that one could define in a way that given InfoWindow has no close button:

```
marker.openInfoWindowHtml("No Close Button",{buttons:{close:{show:4}}});
```

The above however does not apply for v3. Does anybody know a way to do it? I read about an utility that replaces InfoWindow called [InfoBox](https://code.google.com/p/google-maps-utility-library-v3/source/browse/#svn/tags/infobox/1.1.9/src) but it has not been developed for the past 2 years. I'm currently using the latest 3.13 version of Gmaps v3 API.

A workaround with jQuery is acceptable, if there is no better solution.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

### Update

Displaying a `<div>` on top of a google map is straight forward :

example css:

```
div.info {
    position: absolute;
    z-index: 999;
    width: 200px;
    height: 100px;
    display: none;
    background-color: #fff;
    border: 3px solid #ebebeb;
    padding: 10px;
}
```

A `info` class `<div>` somewhere in the markup :

```
<div id="myinfo" class="info"><p>I am a div on top of a google map .. </p></div>
```

Always nice to have a short reference to the div :

```
var info = document.getElementById('myinfo');
```

The more tricky part, showing the `<div>`, how and when - here I just assign a click handler to the map (after it is created) and show the info `<div>` at mouse location XY inside the map :

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'click', function(args) {
  var x=args.pixel.x; //we clicked here
  var y=args.pixel.y;

  info.style.left=x+'px';
  info.style.top=y+'px';
  info.style.display='block';
});
```

What you gain with this is, that the info `<div>` follows you around on the map, every time you click.

[image]

- You will need more styling so it suits your need, eg so it "looks like an InfoBox", but that should be easy to find out, I am not a librarian :)
- And maybe later on something to close the info  with, but that you didn't want in the first place :)

---

### Original answer

**You cant**! There is no way to do this in the current v3.13 [InfoWindow options](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions).

A workaround is to disable the image containing the X :

```
<style>
img[src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt3.png"] {
    display: none;
}
</style>
```

[image]

### *But this is in **no way** advisable*!

`src="http://maps.gstatic.com/mapfiles/api-3/images/mapcnt3.png` is just what the infowindow is referring to *today*. Tomorrow, or in a month, or in a year, this image-reference for sure has changed. As you can see if you search for similar "solutions", made over time - like [this](http://search.missouristate.edu/map/mobile/examples/removeclose.htm). They are all broken today, eg the effort is meaningless.

I think there is extremely good logic in google "refusing" to follow the request for hiding the close-button. If you not need a close-button, what do you need an InfoWindow for anyway? When you are better off just to show a `<div>` on the map.

Comment: Could you instead hint on how to display a `<div>` on the map that looks like an InfoBox?

Comment: "If you not need a close-button, what do you need an InfoWindow for anyway?" - you can close the infoWindow with the mouseout event...

Comment: In my case there is no image with above src but the style with -webkit-mask-image is present.

Answer (score 38):

You can also do it through the css.

```
.gm-style-iw + div {display: none;}
```

---

**edit january 2019**
as @antmeehan said in the comment,

> Google have changed the HTML, and the close button is now a button element rather than a div

So the css code to hide the "x" button is now:

```
.gm-style-iw + button {display: none;}
```

Comment: Worked for me and it seems to be the the best and easies solution

Comment: Still somewhat subject to Google changing how things are implemented - depends on the info window class staying the same, and close button being the immediate next div after it. But at least its simple.

Comment: Google have changed the HTML, and the close button is now a button element rather than a div.

Comment: Thanks for this. one question tho, why did you use `+` in your declaration? It works by declaring `.gm-style-iw button` without the `+` sign. Actually it should be `.gm-style-iw > button` because if you have other custom buttons within the box, it'd be hidden too. Placing it as an answer and referring to this for future users.

Comment: The + operator will select all <button> elements that are placed immediately after elements that are of class gm-style-iw.

The > operator will select all <button> elements where the parent element contains the class .gm-style-iw.

I think both may accomplish the same goal.

Answer (score 17):

if using jquery just add this

```
$(".gm-style-iw").next("div").hide();
```

Comment: you can do this with pure CSS, just use the + symbol to get next sibling: `.gm-style-iw + div { display: none; }`

Answer (score 16):

To extend on **Louis Moore**'s answer, you can also center the text after removing the close button:

```
.gm-style-iw + div {display: none;}
.gm-style-iw {text-align:center;}
```

Without Centering:

[image]

With Centering:

[image]

Comment: This is really the correct and most effective answer by far. But honestly why doesn't google just support hiding it.

Answer (score 12):

Thanks Tushar, but also you need put this code in event handler

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function(){
    $(".gm-style-iw").next("div").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 8):

It should be `.gm-style-iw > button` to avoid other custom buttons we might have within the box to be hidden too:

```
.gm-style-iw > button {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: Thank a lot, save my day. :)

Answer (score 7):

I used the answer given by Tushar Gaurav, but expanded it a little...

```
$(".gm-style-iw:contains(" + infoText + ")").css("left", function() {
    return ($(this).parent().width() - $(this).width()) / 2;
}).next("div").remove();
```

That will remove the X from an infowindow with the text in `infoText`, and then recenter the text as it's off-center after removing the close button.

Just adding this for anyone else who stumbles across this page as I did.

Comment: I like this answer since it allows to change a specific infowindow and not just all. For unknown reason the text is not really centered but can be done with css: text-align: center

Answer (score 6):

```
closeBoxURL: ""
```

as stated before doesn't apply for [InfoWIndow](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions). This is an option on the [InfoBox](http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html).

You may for example use this CSS workaround to remove the X, and the surrounding clickable button:

```
.gm-style-iw + div {
  display: none;
}
```

And as **davidkonrad** said. This is a workaround on the code as it is today. It will likely be changed.

Answer (score 4):

My own way (without Jquery) and with realign to the center of the infoWindow:

```
var content = document.querySelector('.gm-style-iw');
content.parentNode.removeChild(content.nextElementSibling);
content.style.setProperty('width', 'auto', 'important');
content.style.setProperty('right', content.style.left, 'important');
content.style.setProperty('text-align', 'center', 'important');
```

Answer (score 3):

This works

```
.gm-style-iw > button {display: none !important;}
```

Answer (score 2):

My solution:

```
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {

            var wnd = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                content: "<table id='viewObject' >...</table>"
            });

            google.maps.event.addListener(wnd, 'domready', function(){

                $("#viewObject").parent().parent().next().remove();
            });

            wnd.open(map, marker);
        });
```

Comment: Thanks, it works if you only want to remove the x only for some of the info windows

Answer (score 2):

```
=============  HTML  ==============
<agm-map #gm [latitude]="lat" [longitude]="lng" #AgmMap [fitBounds]="true">
 <agm-marker
          (mouseOver)="onMouseOver(infoWindow, gm)"
          (mouseOut)="onMouseOut(infoWindow, gm)"
        >

         <div id="test">
            <agm-info-window #infoWindow></agm-info-window>
          </div>
        </agm-marker>
      </agm-map>

=============  TS  ==============

onMouseOver(infoWindow, gm) {
console.log(infoWindow);
if (gm.lastOpen != null) {
 gm.lastOpen.close();
}
gm.lastOpen = infoWindow;
infoWindow.open();
setTimeout(() => {
  var x = document.getElementsByClassName('gm-ui-hover-effect')[0].remove();
}, 10);
}
onMouseOut(infoWindow, gm) {
gm.lastOpen = infoWindow;
// infoWindow.close();
```

}

Answer (score 2):

Anno domini 2021 this work better for me

```
button.gm-ui-hover-effect {
  display: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use this. This will not hide other images like zoom control, pan control etc.
on dom ready of info window you can use this.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infoWindow, 'domready', function () {

      document.querySelector(".gm-style-iw").nextElementSibling.style.display = "none";
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I can't find correct answer in here, so I fixed it myself. It will work well.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function(){
      $(".gm-style-iw").parent().find("button").removeAttr("style").hide();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

.gm-style-iw + button {display: none !important;}

Comment: What's the difference from [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30293491/17423)?

Answer (score 0):

I couldn't get any of the `$(".gm-style-iw").next("div").hide();` answers to work even when calling the code after the DOM was loaded, since there was a delay between the code being called and the info window being created. What I did was create an interval that runs until it finds the info window and removes the "X" element. If there's a better way please tell me.

```
var removeCloseButton = setInterval(
    function()
    {
        if ($(".gm-style-iw").length)
        {
            $(".gm-style-iw").next("div").remove();
            clearInterval(removeCloseButton);
        }
    },
    10
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Using Archers method I need to do

```
$(".gm-style-iw").css("left", function() { //remove close and recenter
  return ($(this).parent().width() - $(this).find(">:first-child").width()) / 2;
}).next("div").remove();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, 'domready', function() {

    var iwOuter = jQuery('.gm-style-iw');

    // Reference to the div that groups the close button elements.
    var iwCloseBtn = iwOuter.next();

    // Apply the desired effect to the close button
    iwCloseBtn.remove()
});
```

As there is no option to hide this by API parameter, you have to find the element by targeting the content window and remove it.

Hope this helps :)

Answer (score -1):

in jQuery's gmap3 plugin this can be accomplished using

```
google.maps.event.addListener($('#map').gmap3({get:{name:"infowindow"}}), 'domready', function(){
    $(".gm-style-iw").next("div").remove();
});
```

Answer (score -1):

**May 2021** : Add this in your CSS:

```
button.gm-ui-hover-effect {
   visibility: hidden;
}
```

This worked perfectly with Maps API v3.43

Answer (score -2):

Inspect it - it's a div with a class of close on it - you can target it with CSS and set it to `display: none;`

Answer (score -3):

You can just use the option

`closeBoxURL : ""`

http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/infobox/docs/reference.html

**From Google Documentation**

> `closeBoxURL   | string    |`   The URL of the image representing the close box. Note: The default is the URL for Google's standard close box. Set
>   this property to "" if no close box is required.

Example

```
   var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                          closeBoxURL: "",
                          closeBoxMargin : ""

                        });
```

Comment: Err, just ready the convoluted answer above. No idea how it's marked as correct. This is the simple and correct answer! Nice one!

Comment: I did exactly the same as you... "WTF did I just read" was my closest thoughts... Sadly the user "nan" above correctly answered as well but was down voted with the correct answer. I upvoted him and added my own spice to the answer.

Comment: `infowindow != infobox`

Comment: funny thing, if you google for "infobox close button hide", it brings you exactly to this page and this is the only solution that works lol

Comment: also didnt work for me. i think its don't work fo version 3.20

Answer (score -4):

You can set "closeBoxURL" property of the Info Window to "" and it will make the button disappear.

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: contentString,
    closeBoxURL: ""
});
```

Comment: why did I get -1 to my answer?

Comment: yes, not a valid option: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference#InfoWindowOptions

Comment: @nan It's not working for me.. I have tried