# How to bind div position with google map's v3 marker position

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I have one custom div with any info and google map with many markers. On click on marker I want the div to appear next to the marker. I use api v3. Could you help me to find solution?

Actually I want to know offset position of a marker in html window.

Comment: Why don't you just add an infoWindow using the content of the div. Much simpler.

Comment: See this answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/18934205/1407478 how to do exactly that. Just change the map click event with the marker click event.

Comment: The method fromLatLngToContainerPixel of google.maps.MapCanvasProjection would help. This method convert a latlng to pixel position relative to the map container. So you can use the latlng attribute of the marker you clicked and get the pixel value also the offset position of the marker in html window.