# Google maps javascript v3 infoWindow not closeable

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

I want to show an infoWindow without the 'x' in order to make it not closeable by the users. Can it be possible? How can I do that? Have I to use another type of tool?

Comment: check this one...http://stackoverflow.com/a/18934205/1047988

Comment: possible duplicate of [GMaps V3 InfoWindow - disable the close "x" button](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18933367/gmaps-v3-infowindow-disable-the-close-x-button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure if its universally and cross browsed, but you can hack this via css:

```
div.gm-style-iw  + div {
  display:none;
}
```