# Remove "X" from Google Maps infoWindow

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Is there a way to remove the "X" close button from a Google Maps Info window? I am using Google Maps JS API v3.

Here is a screenshot of what I am trying to remove:

[image: infoWindow]

Here is the code I am using to create the map:

```
var locations = [
  ['Bondi Beach', -33.890542, 151.274856, 4],
  ['Coogee Beach', -33.923036, 151.259052, 5],
  ['Cronulla Beach', -34.028249, 151.157507, 3],
  ['Manly Beach', -33.80010128657071, 151.28747820854187, 2],
  ['Maroubra Beach', -33.950198, 151.259302, 1]
];

var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('mapFrame123'), {
  zoom: 10,
  center: new google.maps.LatLng(-33.890542, 151.274856),
  mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
});

var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();

var marker, i;

for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {  
  marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
    map: map
  });
    console.log(marker);

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
    return function() {
      infowindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
      infowindow.open(map, marker);
    }
  })(marker, i));
}
```

Any ideas?

Comment: @Andy that post talks about putting a new div on the map. I am wondering how to style the current infoWindow?

Comment: The accepted answer is providing that as an alternative, yes, but have you looked at the other answers?

Comment: I have tried the answer that sets the url to "", however, it does not seem to be working for me. Any ideas?

Comment: To me, [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21928069/1355856) looks most promising. Maybe give that one a try.