# Google maps function fromLatLngToContainerPixel(LatLng) not working

Tags: javascript, google-maps

Im trying to get a pixel coordinates of a market by using the fromLatLngToContainerPixel(LatLng) function. 
I was not sure how to use it but after searching some examples in SO i think i got it. The problem is the function returns always "undifined".

Google maps api ref: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?csw=1#MapCanvasProjection

Please help.

code:

```
var map, overlay;

function initialize() {
var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gMap'), {
    zoom : 13,
    center : myLatlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    draggable: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true
});

var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
overlay.draw = function () {};
overlay.setMap(map);

var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng, 
    optimized: false, 
    map:map
});

 var projection = overlay.getProjection(); 
        var pixel =     projection.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(marker.getPosition());
        console.log(pixel);
}
google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Comment: You say that the function returns always "undefined". But which function? The only useful one in your snippet is `initialize()`, that doesn't return anything at all. So where is the problem?

Comment: related question: [Google Maps: Get click or marker (x,y) pixel coordinates inside marker click listener](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176753/google-maps-get-click-or-marker-x-y-pixel-coordinates-inside-marker-click-lis)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=en&csw=1#OverlayView):

**`getProjection()`**:
*Returns the MapCanvasProjection object associated with this OverlayView. The projection is not initialized until onAdd is called by the API.*

**`onAdd()`**:  Implement this method to initialize the overlay DOM elements. This method is called once after setMap() is called with a valid map. At this point, panes and projection will have been initialized.

**So the solution is:**
implement the `onAdd()`-method and access the projection inside `onAdd()`:

```
function initialize() {
  var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(-25.363882, 131.044922);
  map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('gMap'), {
    zoom: 13,
    center: myLatlng,
    disableDefaultUI: true,
    draggable: false,
    scrollwheel: false,
    disableDoubleClickZoom: true
  });

  var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatlng,
    optimized: false,
    map: map
  });

  var overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  overlay.draw = function() {};
  overlay.onAdd = function() {
    var projection = this.getProjection();
    var pixel = projection.fromLatLngToContainerPixel(marker.getPosition());
    console.log(pixel);
  };
  overlay.setMap(map);
}
```