# Reposition GoogleMap's center view to infoWindow's pixel position after it has loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3, position

I have a GoogleMap on a page with several markers (ajax'ed) on it. When I click on the marker, an info window opens up with details (also ajax'ed) in it.

I can't figure out how to center the map to have this info window in the middle of the map.

The GoogleMap is loaded like so:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
    zoom: zoomSteps[0],
    center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.227638, 2.213749000000007),
    mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
    mapTypeControl: false,
    streetViewControl: false,
    styles: [{
        featureType: "poi",
        stylers: [{
            visibility: "off"
        }]
    }]
});
```

Also, the `InfoWindow` GoogleMap object is generated like so:

```
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    maxWidth: 400,
});
```

I then perform an ajax request to fetch data to position markers on the map in the `success: function(data) {}`:

```
for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(data[i].latitude, data[i].longitude),
        map: map
    });

    // ...
}
```

In this `for() {}` loop, I add an `EventListener` on each of the generated `marker`:

```
google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
    return function () {
        // open the info window
        infowindow.open(map, marker); 

        // get css load spinner HTML from ajax and populate a div
        var $loader = $('<div/>').addClass('loader').css('overflow', 'hidden').html(data[i].htmlLoader); 

        // inject this div html code into the infowindow
        infowindow.setContent($loader.prop('outerHTML')); 

        // (1)

        // Main function to retrieve data from the SOAP WebService :
        // it takes infoWindow html template from data[i].htmlTemplate,
        // populates it with data fetched from SOAP WebService and sends it back to here        
        MainSearchTool.prototype.loadEntityResults(data[i].ws.data, data[i].htmlTemplate, function (htmlTemplate) {

            // inject newly fetched results into the infowindow
            infowindow.setContent(htmlTemplate);

            /**
             * Here is where I would like to reposition the center
             * of the map to fit the infoWindow 
             * (2)
             */
        });

    }
})(marker, i));
```

In `(2)` I tried (to no avail) to:

1. call `map.setCenter(LatLng)` with `LatLng` being `marker.getPosition()` - works when called in `(1)` but infoWindow is populated with a loading spinner and not the final template at this time ;
2. convert infoWindow `offset()` left and top to `new google.maps.Point()` and convert it back to a `LatLng` object as per [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29177195/2788131);
3. use several techniques to reposition `map` according to specific values;

It seems that I cannot find any specific method to get the map to be centered according to a `LatLng` object that would match the very center of the infoWindow.

Feel free to ask any additionnal info you may find useful.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind.

Calling `infowindow.open(map, marker);` again in `(2)` does the trick.

For further reference.

Answer (score 0):

Let me answer anyway, in the spirit of the question: known size infowindow, known size map.  I set those values in css, see code

After a click on the map we read the location of the marker; convert that location to the corresponding pixel; we add the pixel distance marker to mid-infowindow; we convert that point in coordinates, then center the map to that point.

For my code this means we must center the map 100 pixel above (y direction) the marker.  You might want functions that calculate tat distance for your values (maybe dynamically if you do not fix sizes)

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?libraries=geometry"></script>
<script>
    // @see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25219346/how-to-convert-from-x-y-screen-coordinates-to-latlng-google-maps
    function latLng2Point(latLng, map) {
        var topRight = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
        var bottomLeft = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getSouthWest());
        var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
        var worldPoint = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(latLng);
        return new google.maps.Point((worldPoint.x - bottomLeft.x) * scale, (worldPoint.y - topRight.y) * scale);
    }

    function point2LatLng(point, map) {
        var topRight = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getNorthEast());
        var bottomLeft = map.getProjection().fromLatLngToPoint(map.getBounds().getSouthWest());
        var scale = Math.pow(2, map.getZoom());
        var worldPoint = new google.maps.Point(point.x / scale + bottomLeft.x, point.y / scale + topRight.y);
        return map.getProjection().fromPointToLatLng(worldPoint);
    }

    var map;
    var markers = [];
    var infowindow;

    function senterOnInfowindow(infowindow, marker) {
        var markerposition = marker.getPosition();
        // let's add pixels to that to the north: Y-offset + half the height of the infowindow
        var xy = latLng2Point(markerposition, map);
        xy.x += 0; // if needed, ajust x
        xy.y -= 100;
        var newCenter = point2LatLng(xy, map);
        map.setCenter(newCenter);
    }

    function initMap() {
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            zoom: 19,
            center: new google.maps.LatLng(46.227638, 2.213749000000007),
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
            mapTypeControl: false,
            streetViewControl: false
        });
        // place a few markers
        var markerlocations = [
            [46.2276, 2.2137, 'location 1'],
            [46.2277, 2.2136, 'location 2'],
            [46.2278, 2.2135, 'location 3'],
            [46.2279, 2.2134, 'location 4']
        ];
        for (var i in markerlocations) {
            var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(markerlocations[i][0], markerlocations[i][1]),
                title: markerlocations[i][2],
                map: map
            });

            markers.push(marker);
            google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function(marker, i) {
                return function() {
                    infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
                        width: 400,
                        height: 300,
                        content: '<div id="mydiv">' + markerlocations[i][2] + '</div>'
                    });
                    infowindow.open(map, marker);
                    //senterOnInfowindow(infowindow, marker)
                }
            })(marker, i));

        }
    }
    window.onload = initMap;
</script>
<style>
    #mydiv {
        height: 100px;
        width: 200px;
    }

    #map {
        height: 500px;
        width: 700px;
    }
</style>
<div id="map"></div>
```