# google map get latitude, longitude from pixel x,y

Tags: javascript, html, google-maps, latitude-longitude

I want to get the coordinates of the place I want on my map. If you select a point of x:400px, y:400px in a map of size 500px * 500px like the example in the code below, you want to get the latitude and longitude there. I can now implement this via click event. But what I want is to use it through a method, not through an event. For example, if I give x:240px, y:300px as parameters, I want to return (latitude: 35.61823, longitude: 125.142314) regardless of the shape. The code below implements this as a click event.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Getting Properties With Event Handlers</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script
    src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=YOUR_API_KEY&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly"
    defer></script>
  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var seoul = { lat: 37.56532723199129, lng: 126.98799094110187 };
      const map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map"), {
        zoom: 15,
        center: seoul,
      });
      map.addListener("click", (mapsMouseEvent) => {
        console.log(mapsMouseEvent.pixel)
        console.log(mapsMouseEvent.latLng.toJSON())
      });
    }
  </script>
</head>
<body>  
    <div id="map" style = "width:500px; height:500px;"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

related question: [Google Maps: Get click or marker (x,y) pixel coordinates inside marker click listener](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29176753/google-maps-get-click-or-marker-x-y-pixel-coordinates-inside-marker-click-lis)

Note that the center of the map (atitude: 35.61823, longitude: 125.142314) is at (x:250px, y: 250px), not at (x:240px, y:300px)

Use the [`fromContainerPixelToLatLng`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#MapCanvasProjection.fromContainerPixelToLatLng) method to translate container pixels to geographic coordinates.

To get access to the [MapCanvasProjection](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#MapCanvasProjection), make an instance of the [OverlayView](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#OverlayView) class, and call [`getProjection`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/overlay-view#OverlayView.getProjection) on that.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'projection_changed', function() {
  overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
  overlay.draw = function() {};
  overlay.setMap(map);
  google.maps.event.addListener(overlay, 'projection_changed', function() {
    // x:240px, y:300px as parameters, I want to return (latitude: 35.61823, longitude: 125.142314) 
    var latLng = overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(250, 250));
    console.log(latLng.toUrlValue(6));
  })
})
```

**code snippet:**

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <title>Getting Properties With Event Handlers</title>
  <script src="https://polyfill.io/v3/polyfill.min.js?features=default"></script>
  <script src="https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?key=AIzaSyCkUOdZ5y7hMm0yrcCQoCvLwzdM6M8s5qk&callback=initMap&libraries=&v=weekly" defer></script>
  <script>
    function initMap() {
      var seoul = {
        lat: 37.56532723199129,
        lng: 126.98799094110187
      };
      const map = new google.maps.Map(
        document.getElementById("map"), {
          zoom: 15,
          center: seoul,
        });
      google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'projection_changed', function() {
          overlay = new google.maps.OverlayView();
          overlay.draw = function() {};
          overlay.setMap(map);
          google.maps.event.addListener(overlay, 'projection_changed', function() {
            // x:240px, y:300px as parameters, I want to return (latitude: 35.61823, longitude: 125.142314) 
            var latLng = overlay.getProjection().fromContainerPixelToLatLng(new google.maps.Point(250, 250));
            console.log(latLng.toUrlValue(6));
          })
       })

        map.addListener("click", (mapsMouseEvent) => {
          console.log(mapsMouseEvent.pixel)
          console.log(mapsMouseEvent.latLng.toJSON())
        });
      }
  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="map" style="width:500px; height:500px;"></div>
</body>

</html>
```